# Dplyr filter using range across two columns

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

Apologies if this is a duplicate, but I cannot seem to find what I am looking for.

I am trying to filter data into 4 sub-sets using a specified range between two columns. I have gotten as far as the following before I get stuck. I think the solution lies somewhere in `between`, `filter_all()` or `filter_if()` but I cannot get it to work. Any thoughts, solutions would be great, thank you. I am trying to split into the following periods 1 - 1815-1865; 2- 1865-1915; 3- 1915-1965 and 1965-2013.

Expected output for P2 (1865-1915) as long as either the upper or lower threshold takes the age to potentially sit within the range I would include it.

[image: Table]

### Code

```r
## Read in data
dat<-read_csv("data/Iceland.csv")

dat <- rbind(dat)

## Arrange the whole data set by age

dat <-dat %>% arrange(dat)

## Calculate ranges for periods

dat$upper<-dat$year+dat$year_error
dat$lower<-dat$year-dat$year_error

### Split into periods

p1<-dat %>% filter(between(upper:lower, 1815, 1865))
```

### Data

```
structure(list(year = c(1800.13122, 1816.105967, 1836.292674, 
1840.330016, 1856.479382, 1864.566799), y = c(-0.41, -0.31, -0.27, 
-0.25, -0.15, -0.15), y_error = c(0.18, 0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 0.18, 
0.19), year_error = c(24.59408182, 29.61627391, 29.34693518, 
30.02607322, 34.75414444, 30.78615486), upper = c(1824.72530182, 
1845.72224091, 1865.63960918, 1870.35608922, 1891.23352644, 1895.35295386
), lower = c(1775.53713818, 1786.48969309, 1806.94573882, 1810.30394278, 
1821.72523756, 1833.78064414)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: What should happen when the range defined by the upper and lower bounds overlaps with two intervals?

Comment: They go in both intervals and are repeated

Comment: Could you include the expected output from your sample dataset?

Comment: @Peter I have added a table of expected results as an example for period 2, apologies I can't figure out how to do the markdown table

Comment: Are you sure you need to duplicate values exactly on the threshold? That's the tricky part. Your sample data doesn't have any values of, say, exactly 1815. If that complication can be ignored, then you can do `dat |> mutate(period = cut(year, breaks = c(0, 1815, 1865, 1915, 1965, 2013)) |> group_by(period) |> group_split()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could also set up a data.frame / tibble with periods and join it with `join_by(overlaps())`:

```r
library(dplyr)
# adjust sigfig for printing
options(pillar.sigfig = 6)
# define periods:
periods <- tribble(~period, ~start, ~end,
                         1,   1815, 1865, 
                         2,   1865, 1915,
                         3,   1915, 1965,
                         4,   1965, 2013)
# join by overlaps, default bounds are [], i.e. <= and >=
dat <- dat %>% left_join(periods, join_by(overlaps(lower, upper, start, end)))
dat
#> # A tibble: 10 × 9
#>       year     y y_error year_error   upper   lower period start   end
#>      <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 1800.13 -0.41    0.18    24.5941 1824.73 1775.54      1  1815  1865
#>  2 1816.11 -0.31    0.19    29.6163 1845.72 1786.49      1  1815  1865
#>  3 1836.29 -0.27    0.19    29.3469 1865.64 1806.95      1  1815  1865
#>  4 1836.29 -0.27    0.19    29.3469 1865.64 1806.95      2  1865  1915
#>  5 1840.33 -0.25    0.19    30.0261 1870.36 1810.30      1  1815  1865
#>  6 1840.33 -0.25    0.19    30.0261 1870.36 1810.30      2  1865  1915
#>  7 1856.48 -0.15    0.18    34.7541 1891.23 1821.73      1  1815  1865
#>  8 1856.48 -0.15    0.18    34.7541 1891.23 1821.73      2  1865  1915
#>  9 1864.57 -0.15    0.19    30.7862 1895.35 1833.78      1  1815  1865
#> 10 1864.57 -0.15    0.19    30.7862 1895.35 1833.78      2  1865  1915

# for p2:
dat %>% filter(period == 2)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 9
#>      year     y y_error year_error   upper   lower period start   end
#>     <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 1836.29 -0.27    0.19    29.3469 1865.64 1806.95      2  1865  1915
#> 2 1840.33 -0.25    0.19    30.0261 1870.36 1810.30      2  1865  1915
#> 3 1856.48 -0.15    0.18    34.7541 1891.23 1821.73      2  1865  1915
#> 4 1864.57 -0.15    0.19    30.7862 1895.35 1833.78      2  1865  1915
```

Input data:

```r
dat <- structure(list(year = c(1800.13122, 1816.105967, 1836.292674, 
1840.330016, 1856.479382, 1864.566799), y = c(-0.41, -0.31, -0.27, 
-0.25, -0.15, -0.15), y_error = c(0.18, 0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 0.18, 
0.19), year_error = c(24.59408182, 29.61627391, 29.34693518, 
30.02607322, 34.75414444, 30.78615486), upper = c(1824.72530182, 
1845.72224091, 1865.63960918, 1870.35608922, 1891.23352644, 1895.35295386
), lower = c(1775.53713818, 1786.48969309, 1806.94573882, 1810.30394278, 
1821.72523756, 1833.78064414)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am misunderstanding what you are trying to do, I think you can do this using `&` (AND) inside `filter()`. For your four sets this would be:

```
# P1
data %>% filter(upper >= 1815 & lower <= 1865)

# P2
data %>% filter(upper >= 1865 & lower <= 1915)

# P3 (empty)
data %>% filter(upper >= 1915 & lower <= 1965)

# P4 (empty)
data %>% filter(upper >= 1965 & lower <= 2013)
```

This is the output for the "P2" set:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 6
   year     y y_error year_error upper lower
  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 1836. -0.27    0.19       29.3 1866. 1807.
2 1840. -0.25    0.19       30.0 1870. 1810.
3 1856. -0.15    0.18       34.8 1891. 1822.
4 1865. -0.15    0.19       30.8 1895. 1834.
```

I am using `>=` and `<=` since you commented that the intervals should be inclusive.